# R numerical method similar to Vpasolve in Matlab

Tags: r, matlab

I am trying to solve a numerical equation in R but would want a method which perform similar to vpasolve in Matlab. I have a non linear equation (involving lot of log functions) which when solve in R with uniroot gives me complete different answer compared to what vpasolve gives in matlab.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55723807/13513328 or https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rootSolve/vignettes/rootSolve.pdf

Answer (score 0):

First, a word of caution: it's often much more productive to learn that there's a **better** way to do something than the way you are used to doing.

### edit

I went back to MATLAB and realized that the "vpa" collection is using extended precision.  Is that absolutely necessary for your purposes? If not, then my suggestions below may suffice.
If you do require extended precision, then perhaps `Rmpfr::unirootR` function will suffice.  I would like to point out that, since all these solvers are generating an approximate solution (as opposed to analytic), the use of extended precision operations seems a bit pointless.

Next, you need to determine whether  `MATLAB::vpasolve` or `uniroot` is getting you the correct answer.  Or maybe you simply are converging to a root that's not the one you want, in which case you need to read up on setting limits on the starting conditions or the search region.

Finally, in addition to `uniroot`, I recommend you learn to use the R packages `BBsolve` , `nleqslv`, `rootsolve`,  and `ktsolve` (disclaimer: I am the owner and maintainer of `ktsolve`).  These packages are pretty flexible and may lead you to better solutions to your original problem.